# How to efficiently normalize mysql table

Tags: mysql, database

[image: Database model[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQAU7.png)

I want to know if I normalized the table well using the diagram.

Comment: Are you reading Beginning MySQL Database Design and Optimization? Its description of normalization is poor. Google "normalization" and download stanford.edu or sfu.ca slides or textbook pdfs. To normalize you must know all *functional dependencies* in your table.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really told us what you're trying to accomplish, but a few things I would change just from making a few assumptions:

1)  You should have a separate table to store the Authors and Bios, with the fields of AuthorID, AuthorName, and Bio.  Reference the AuthorID in the main table instead of the actual name.

2)  Do the same thing for the Subject; SubjectID, SubjectName

3)  Have a table dedicated to the Publishers; PublisherID, PublisherName

This will help you minimize the amount of data stored in the main table.  You'll also want to add foreign keys to the main table that link to the child table (Main.AuthorID -> Author.AuthorID, Main.SubjectID -> Subject.SubjectID, etc).

Comment: Normalization does not introduce new columns (eg IDs) It just rearranges old ones.